# How to access list from JSP in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsp

In JSP I have a list. It contains String type of elements. I want to access this list in JavaScript. How can I do it?

**JSPCode**

```
    <%! List l;%>
    <% 
       l=(List)request.getAttribute("listResource");
    %>
```

**JavaScriptCode**

```
  function verify_Resources()
  {
      var resourceId=document.getElementById("res").value;
      var rid=<%=l%>
  }
```

I want check wether the Selected id is in the List or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to access the jsp array variable into javascipt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556047/how-to-access-the-jsp-array-variable-into-javascipt)

Comment: How is that different from your last question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize the list to JSON.