# How to compare javascript variable with Jsp variable?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to compare a javascript variable with a jsp variable. How can I do this?

```
 function verify_details()
   {
    var resourceId=document.getElementById("res").value;'
    <%! String rId;%>
    <%
    for(int i=0;i<l.size();i++)
    {
      rId=l.get(i).toString();
       System.out.println("Elements Are:"+rid);
    %>
       if(resourceId==rId)
        alert("Alloted");
       else
           alert("Not Alloted");  

   <%}%>

   }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access list from JSP in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567762/how-to-access-list-from-jsp-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be doing this in the first place. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files).

If you really want to, make a new JSP with this code in it, pass the variable you want to compare as a parameter (call that page with AJAX) and get the result.

But, that's overly complicated and this situation should really never occur in code that is well structured.

Answer (score 0):

Use some control like 'hidden' or any other. Its value will be accessible in both `javascript` and `jsp`.