# How can we get JavaScript array by JSP scriptlet

Tags: javascript, jsp

I need JavaScript array/multidimensional which is returned by Java class,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var strComboValue  = <%=DBComboOptions.getOptions(combos)%>;
</script>
```

Here, `strComboValue` is a JavaScript variable and the `DBComboOptions.getOptions(combos)` returns array in Java class. Now I want that array in JavaScript.

Comment: I don't know jsp but it seems that you've got the array in `strComboValue`

Comment: Use some json encoding library and call json encode on `DBComboOptions.getOptions(combos)`

Comment: @Esailija : this should be an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Populating JavaScript Array from JSP List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040645/populating-javascript-array-from-jsp-list)

Comment: @JBNizet I'll rather close as duplicate :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just let Java/JSP print a syntactically valid JS array syntax. Keep in mind that Java/JSP and JavaScript doesn't run in sync. Java/JSP produces HTML as one large `String` and JS is just part of it. JS ultimately runs in the webbrowser once it has retrieved all that HTML output from Java/JSP.

Assuming that you ultimately want the following valid JS array syntax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var strComboValue = [ "one", "two", "three" ];
</script>
```

Then you should write your Java/JSP code accordingly so that it prints exactly that syntax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var strComboValue = [ 
<% 
    String[] options = DBComboOptions.getOptions(combos);
    for (int i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
%>
        "<%= options[i] %>"
<%
        if (i + 1 < options.length) {
%>
            ,
<%
        }
    }
%>
    ];
</script>
```

It's only terribly unreadable (and not only because of using [old fashioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) *scriptlets* instead of taglibs). Easier, however, is to grab a JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) library like [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and create an additional method `getOptionsAsJson()` which does something like the following:

```
public getOptionsAsJson(Object value) {
    return new Gson().toJson(getOptions(value));
}
```

And finally use it instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var strComboValue = <%=DBComboOptions.getOptionsAsJson(combos)%>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

your can use json lib, on http://json.org there are many json librarys,
i.e.

```
int[] arr = new int [] {1,2,3}; // java
```

convert to:

```
var arr = [1,2,3];  // javascript
```