# JSP array to Javascript

Tags: arrays

I need to pass this below array [aLocations] from jsp.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var aLocations = new Array();
  var aTitles = new Array();
  var aDetails = new Array();

  aLocations = ['keswick,cumbria,uk','grasmere,cumbria,uk','ambleside,cumbria,uk'];

</script>
```

if i tried like this, it is not working:

```
<%
ArrayList<String> myArr = new ArrayList<String>();
        myArr.add("keswick,cumbria,uk");
        myArr.add("grasmere,cumbria,uk");
        myArr.add("ambleside,cumbria,uk");
%>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var aLocations = new Array();
  var aTitles = new Array();
  var aDetails = new Array();

  aLocations = <%=myArr%>;

</script>
```

what is the best approach to pass from JSP?

Answer (score 0):

You need a library.
For example with http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ you can:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
aLocations = <%=gson.toJson(myArr)%>;
```

or see https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide for documentation.

Without a library you need to manually create a structure like ["imtem1","item2",..,"itemn"] with iteration, string concatenation, escape handling, etc. See [Populating JavaScript Array from JSP List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040645/populating-javascript-array-from-jsp-list)

Comment: thanks for ur quick response. cant be achievable without that library?

Comment: i tried as u mentioned but i am getting this error:                                                             "The method fromObject(ArrayList<String>) is undefined for the type JSONArray"