# How to transfer an <option> tag's element into an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, html, arrays, jsp

How should I  get all the options inside a dropdown list (under html) and convert it into an array in Javasctipt? 
The code snippet comes from a jsp/ html. 
The Form.projectList is Java object call

```
<c:forEach items="${Form.projectList}" var="val">
   <option ${Form.project eq val.projectId?'selected="selected"':''} 
           value="<c:out value="${val.projectId}"/>"><c:out value="${val.project}"/></option>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: If you're doing it in Javascript, it doesn't matter where it comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the id of the select and jquery to populate an array. Like the following

```
var arr=new Array();
$("#dropdwonid option").each(function()
{
    arr.push($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a JS array like you usually would. Then push the values in by placing the array in you JSP loop.

```
<script language="javascript">
var myJsArry = [];  // JS array
// Your JSP loop

<c:forEach items="${Form.projectList}" var="val">

    myJsArry.push(${val.projectId);  // fill your JS array

    <option ${Form.project eq val.projectId?'selected="selected"':''} 
        value="<c:out value="${val.projectId}"/>"><c:out value="${val.project}"/>
    </option>
</c:forEach>
</script>
```

[Populate JavaScript Array from JSP List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040645/populating-javascript-array-from-jsp-list)

Comment: I don't think you can push the items into the array using the JS syntax inside html , is there another solution to this?
Because right now, I am just printing all the items of the list

Comment: Yes. You can create a script tag in your JSP file and place the JS variable in your loop. I've done it often in several projects at my job.

Comment: Is it something like this ? I am not really familiar with Js syntax , so please point out if I did anything wrong. 
Thanks !
`<c:forEach items="${submitExpressionForm.projectList}" var="val">
<script type="text/javascript">
ProjectsArray.push(  <c:out value="${val.project}"/>);
</script>
</c:forEach>`

Comment: Also, 
I think what you told me works now. However, I am not getting the right value. i.e, I am not printing out the correct name of each items in the array. I am getting a bunch of random numbers

Comment: Change ${val.projectId} to ${val.project}

Answer (score 0):

You need the name of your `select` element and access the `options` collection off of it. For example, if you had a `form` named `myForm` and a `select` element called `myItems` then you would access the list of options in that drop down like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < document.myForm.myItems.options.length; i++)
{
   alert(document.myForm.myItems.options[i].value);
}
```