# Appending JSTL ArrayList<String> to a Javascript String

Tags: javascript, java, arraylist

I am trying to append a ArrayList to a JavaScript String variable using foreach loop but for some reason it doesn't seem to work. I have been trying to fix this problem for 2 days, but no luck yet. Can anyone help with this? Here's the code.

```
<div id="graphdiv"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var s = "";
    <c:forEach items="${dateAndWaitTimes}" var="item">
        s.append(${item});
    </c:forEach>
    g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graphdiv"), s);
</script>
```

Here dateAndWaitTimes contains the ArrayList of String, returned by the controller.

-

### Output that I am getting:

[image]

### Expected Output:

[image]

Comment: you can't mix variables of 2 languages like that. Each language runs in different place at different time

Comment: Thanks,So is there any way to append the values of Java Arralylist<String> to a JavaScript string?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040645/populating-javascript-array-from-jsp-list

Comment: PM 77-1: I guess I am doing the same thing?

Comment: Try declaring "s =new Array();" and then s.push() instead of s.append()

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're getting array values correctly but nothing display correct.
one solution might be : put Java arraylist values into JS arrayList and then print JS arrayList values.

**Code :**

```
<script language="javascript">
$(function(){
    var values = new Array();        
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${dateAndWaitTimes}" varStatus="status">
        values.push("${item}");   
    </c:forEach>
    alert(" VALUES => "+values[0]);
    alert(" VALUES => "+values[1]);
    //alert(" VALUES => "+values[2]);

});
```

Comment: this should work. this is using JQuery so you should add it to your js file. or i can change to JS it for you as soon as possible.

Comment: Mohammad Reza Khatami, can you please change it to JS?

Comment: you can delete $function() then it doesn't work with JQuery anymore but i'm not sure in that, try to do it and if it doesn't work, put JQuery api in script src at top of your current page. good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.