# How to iterate a jsp list in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have list object passed from java to jsp. I want to iterate that array list in my javascript function.

For example, I have list called "arrayList" in java and I am getting that in my jsp as

```
 <span id="valueList" style="display: none;">${arrayList}</span>
```

In javascript I tried fetching it as

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ranges = new Array();
    ranges.push($("#valueList").text());
    $.each(array, function(i, item) {
        console.log('val is '+item) 
    });
});
```

Here, in console, all the values are printing like [1,2,3,4,5,6] instead I want this to be printed separately.

Comment: Well, you push `$("#valueList").text()`, which is the String representation of the Array. Have you tried just pushing `$("#valueList")` instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populating JavaScript Array from JSP List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040645/populating-javascript-array-from-jsp-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try this

```
//Assumming your value is like this or you should assign json string in valueList span 
// Other wise you can use jstl to iterate the array
<span id="valueList" style="display: none;">[1,2,3,4,5,6]</span>

var ranges = [];
ranges = JSON.parse($("#valueList").text());
$.each(ranges , function(i, item) {
    console.log('val is '+ item) 
});
```